# Signal readyRead not emitted, when I create QSerialPort from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, serial-port

I have a class COMPort for interaction with QSerialPort. When I create exemplar this class from main thread, then I can send and receive data and signal readyRead will be emitted. But when I try make the same from thread, signal readyRead will be not emitted.

```
void GetSN_Thread::run()
{
    // Connect to serial port with default baudrate
    serialPort = new COMPort();

    if (!(serialPort->connectCOM(portName, DEFAULT_BAUDRATE)))
    {
        //Send signal -> Unable connect to this com port
        emit showMsg("Unable to connect to " + portName + "\n");
        return;
    }

    emit showMsg(portName + " connected" + "\n");

    serialPort->write("Hello");
```

After this I wait a signal readyRead, but this was not emitted.

When I make this from main thread, then it all works.

```
serialPort = new COMPort();
QString btlMsg= "";
if (serialPort->connectCOM(comName, comBR))
{
    serialPort->write(COMMAND_START);
    rcvThr = new ReceiveThread(serialPort, 4);
    connect(rcvThr,SIGNAL(sendString(QString)), this, SLOT(msgHandler(QString)));
    rcvThr->start();
}
```

And code for COMPort:

```
bool COMPort::connectCOM(QString name, int baudrate)
{
    this->portName = name;
    this->baudrate = baudrate;
    connect(&serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readDataCOM()));
    serialPort.setPortName(this->portName);
    serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort.setParity(serialPort.NoParity);
    serialPort.setBaudRate((QSerialPort::BaudRate)this->baudrate);
    serialPort.setStopBits(serialPort.OneStop);

    serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    if (serialPort.isOpen())
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Method for reading data:

```
void COMPort::readDataCOM()
{
    char chData;
    while (serialPort.read(&chData,1))
    {
       queueMsg.append(chData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your debug output + your .h file.

Answer (score -2):

Everything ok... but where is signal emitted? I don't see anywhere in code emit readyRead(); and nowhere is connected showMsg(); signal.